# Mp3 play class play songs in list but wait till one finishes before continuing

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, datagridview, thread-sleep

I am currently working off of this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14709/Playing-MP3s-using-MCI?msg=4309683#xx4309683xx) on playing mp3 files using c# and winforms, but I added a datagridview to list the songs, now when I click on a song in the grid it plays the song just fine but it only plays that one song, what I would like to do is once the song is done playing to move on to the next song in the list.  I've tried Thread.Sleep with the audiolenght as the time but that just stops the whole application from working until it the sleep is done which is not what I want at all, I am sort of new to winforms so if anyone can guide me to what I need to change to make it work I would really appreciate it.  Here is my code that I've got so far:

```
private void dgvTracks_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayFiles(e.RowIndex);
    }
    public void PlayFiles(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            int eof = dgvTracks.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = index; index <= eof; i++)
            {
                if (File.Exists(dsStore.Tables["Track"].Rows[i]["Filepath"].ToString()))
                {
                    PlayFile(dsStore.Tables["Track"].Rows[i]["Filepath"].ToString());
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mplayer.AudioLength));
                }
                else
                {
                    Exception a = new Exception("File doesn't exists");
                    throw a;
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
    public void PlayFile(string filename)
    {
        mplayer.Open(filename);
        mplayer.Play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `mplayer` is an instance of `System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer`.

You can subscribe to the `MediaPlayer.MediaEnded` event, and use the event handler to start playing the next file.  You'll need to store the currently playing index somewhere.

```
...

int currentPlayIndex = -1;

...

mplayer.MediaEnded += OnMediaEnded;

...

private void OnMediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // if we want to continue playing...
    PlayNextFile();
}

...

public void PlayNextFile()
{
    PlayFiles(currentPlayIndex + 1);
}

public void PlayFiles(int index)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        currentPlayIndex = -1;

        int eof = dgvTracks.Rows.Count;  
        for (int i = index; index <= eof; i++)  
        {  
            if (File.Exists(dsStore.Tables["Track"].Rows[i]["Filepath"].ToString()))  
            {  
                currentPlayIndex = i;  // <--- save index

                PlayFile(dsStore.Tables["Track"].Rows[i]["Filepath"].ToString());  
                Application.DoEvents();  
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mplayer.AudioLength));  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                Exception a = new Exception("File doesn't exists");  
                throw a;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Stop` and `Close` previous playing before playing new audio. for example if you use [`MediaPlayer.Play`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.play)

```
using System.Windows.Media;

MediaPlayer mplayer = new MediaPlayer();

public void PlayFile(string filename)
{
    mplayer.Stop();
    mplayer.Close();
    mplayer.Open(filename);
    mplayer.Play();
}
```